# Making a random tone-sequence in R

Tags: r, random

I would like to generate random tone sequences in R (likewise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-tone_technique) for creating rule-based items. I'm interested, if someone could suggest R packages, which could sonify data for making melodies based on number sequences (for pitch and duration of a tone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/tuneR.pdf) is a package to analyze music, that might help.

[Here](http://music.informatics.indiana.edu/courses/I547/materials/Rwav.pdf) is an example you can try out.

Replicating something similar like the answer to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782580/how-can-i-play-birthday-music-using-r) is maybe rather what you want. There the OP requests code to play the happy-birthday song in R. They code in the answer has, notes, pitch and duration, that you can easily define by yourself and sample randomly from to generate a song.

I think that it might be simpler to do most of these things in python.

Hope this helps!