# Drive sound card from R

Tags: r, audio

I am working on an experiment that utilizes a sound card to play sound and output electrical signals from a multi-channel sound card. From MatLab, I can directly drive each channel, but I would prefer to use R. I have been able to make a multi-channel file and name the channels, but I'm unable to get them to play properly. I have set the soundcard as the default and when I play the test in the config window in the 'Sound' window, but when I run my code it does not play. The code opens WMP and a file plays that is the correct length for the signal I created, but I'm not getting sound from the speakers and I'm not able to measure an electrical signal from the other channels that I have set up. 
Windows 7
Soundcard: Lynx E44
R 3.4.4

```
library("seewave")
library("tuneR")
s1 <- 10*sin(2*pi*440*seq(0,1,length.out=8000))
s1_multi <- WaveMC(data = cbind(s1, s1, s1, s1),
               samp.rate=8000, 
               bit=16)
 colnames(s1_multi) <- c("FL", "FR", "FC", "LF")
setWavPlayer(shQuote("C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe"))

listen(s1_multi)
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to drive the channels of the sound card directly from R?

---

I posted the same question to the seewave developers message board and was informed why my exact code didn't work (listen() for WaveMC plays the first channel only). But my bigger question is if there is a way to directly drive a sound card from R, or if it must go through a third party player. So far I have tried tuneR and seewave.

Thanks.

Comment: The above code works for me (i.e I run it and it plays a sound using windows media player).

Comment: Thank you. I did get that part to work. I left the main text for context, but I'm hoping someone has some insight into using R to directly control the sound card without having to initialize windows media player.

Comment: @jason was your question answered?

Comment: I don't think that it was. I need to control multiple outputs from a sound card simultaneously. I can play single channels, and I can create multi-channel files, but I still have yet to find a way to play multiple channels (more than two - I have gotten stereo files to work).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `audio` package.

## Star Wars Imperial March with R

#### Let's write down some notes and durations:

```
p <- "A3 
      A3 A3 A3 F3 C3# A3 F3 C3# A3
      F4 F4 F4 F4# C3# G3 F3 C3# A3"

d <- c(2, 
       1, 1, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 2,
       1, 1, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 2)
```

#### Make an audio wave dataframe:

```
w <- make_wave(pitch = p, duration = d, tempo = 120, sample_rate= 44100)
```

This is using a slightly adapted version of [Nick Kennedy's phantastic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31783039/9406040).

#### ...and play it directly from the console:

```
audio::play(w)
```

---

## Explanation

What you basically need is a table with frequencies and durations. This could also be achieved via lookup table.  Once you have frequencies and durations of each note, you can turn it easily into an audio wave with `make_sine()` and play it.

Attention: tuneR also has a function called `play()` which works differently and can lead to errors due to masking.

---

## Function

```
make_wave <- function(pitch, duration, tempo, sample_rate){
    # Credit to Nick Kennedy
    require(dplyr)

    notes <- c(A = 0, B = 2, C = 3, D = 5, E = 7, F = 8, G = 10)

    # remove leading, trailing, and consecutive spaces (and some line breaks)
    pitch <- gsub("\n", " ", pitch)
    pitch <- gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", pitch, perl=TRUE)

    # split notes, add duration
    x <- data_frame(pitch = strsplit(pitch, " ")[[1]],
                    duration = duration)

    # calculate frequency
    x <-
        x %>%
        mutate(octave = substring(pitch, nchar(pitch)) %>%
        {suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))} %>%
            ifelse(is.na(.), 4, .),
        note = notes[substr(pitch, 1, 1)],
        note = note + grepl("#", pitch) -
            grepl("b", pitch) + octave * 12 +
            12 * (note < 3),
        freq = 2 ^ ((note - 60) / 12) * 440)


    # create fade to remove clipping
    fade <- seq(0, 1, 50 / sample_rate)


    # turn frequency and duration into sound
    make_sine <- function(freq, duration) {
        # create audio wave
        wave <- sin(seq(0, duration / tempo * 60, 1 / sample_rate) *
                        freq * 2 * pi)

        # apply fade to audio wave
        wave * c(fade, rep(1, length(wave) - 2 * length(fade)), rev(fade))
    }

    # create waveform
    wave_df <-
        mapply(make_sine, x$freq, x$duration) %>%
        do.call("c", .)

    return(wave_df) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I might be missing something, but I'm not sure how this addresses the multiple channel issue. I'm trying to output simultaneously over several channels from the sound card.