# Can R trigger/play mp3 sound file?

Tags: r, mp3

Is there a way to play mp3 sound file using R? I want to trigger the file depending on several input values. All help appreciated.

Comment: There is another topic about this on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782580/how-can-i-play-birthday-music-using-r